# control Matlab workers or labs

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

In a parfor loop of Matlab when workers finish their execution they stays active (0 CPU usage) until the rest of workers complete their computing since the `matlabpool close` command is outside the `parfor` loop. Could I control worker execution individually and free workers dynamically as they finish?.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Not if you're using `matlabpool` and `parfor`. `matlabpool` explicitly reserves the use of those workers for you until you release them with `matlabpool close`.

If you set up your algorithm to use [`Jobs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/createjob.html) and [`Tasks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/createtask.html), they will be freed up dynamically when they've finished their allotted tasks. Although `parfor` is typically as easy as it gets to implement simple parallelisation, for many algorithms it's not really much harder to implement  it using `Jobs` and `Tasks` once you've worked it out for the first time.